# how to cast RemoteConfigValue to Map in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-remote-config

I want to cast `RemoteConfigValue` to Flutter `Map<String, dynamic>` as I am using Firebase remote config set `JSON` data as a value in the firebase console.

I not getting any function with gives me JSON/Map value instead of RemoteConfigValue.

```
final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
remoteConfig.setDefaults(<String, dynamic>{});
try {
  await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
  await remoteConfig.activateFetched();

  print(remoteConfig.getValue("MyKey"));

} on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {
  print(exception.toString());
} catch (exception) {
  print(exception.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out -

Step 1: get string value from `RemoteConfigValue` like `remoteConfig.getString("UAE")` this or `remoteConfig.getValue("UAE").asString()` like this

Step 2: cast that string value into `Map` using `json.decode`:

Example:

```
Map<String, dynamic> mapValues = json.decode(remoteConfig.getValue("MyKey").asString());      
print(mapValues["countryName"]);
```